# Why is getCallingActivity always returning null?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a welcome screen that can be started as the first activity in my app, or it can be started by the main activity that the user spends their time in. I want it to act slightly differently when it's started from the home screen (or any other app) or the main activity.

Calling `getCallingActivity()` in onCreate seems to always return null, regardless of what called the activity. This is strange, because it did work earlier, which is how I found what format the string returns in (which should be in the documentation anyway). I can't see what could have affected it, because the only thing that happens before calling `getCallingActivity()` is calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. I am calling the activity with `startActivityForResult(welcomeIntent, RESULT_WELCOME)`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative way to get this info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass an extra in the `Intent` used with `startActivityForResult()`, indicating which mode you want. Read that extra via `getIntent().getXXXExtra()` (`XXX` depends on what data type you choose) in `onCreate()` of the newly-started activity.

Comment: Ah, of course. It's obvious now that you mention it. Nevertheless, do you know why the method I described didn't work?

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir: No, I would expect `getCallingActivity()` to work. That being said, the `Intent` extra approach is a bit more flexible -- it will survive refactoring, for example, where if you rename or move the calling activity, you would need to update your `getCallingActivity()` logic to match.

Comment: Which MODES are you referring to in this answer? Thanks

Comment: @Eenvincible: The ones from the question ("I want it to act slightly differently when it's started from the home screen (or any other app) or the main activity.")

Comment: I see. I have a problem with my code here too. I found out that the current activity does not remember the calling activity and that is why setResult does not work even though it is being called. I am so banging my head on the table here. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Dogcat: Perhaps because I answered the question "Is there an alternative way to get this info?".

Comment: @CommonsWare, forgive me my naivety - for some weird reason I thought the main question was "Why is getCallingActivity always returning null?". Stupid me.

Answer (score 9):

It's a known issue: getCallingActivity() returns actual data only if the activity has been started in the same task (see the "Tasks and Back Stack" tutorial). Same goes for starting activities for result properly (they can't be single-instanced and you can't use "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK").

Answer (score 6):

Everyone seems to be pointing to the same solution but nobody is putting it in clear words.
Let me do that.

It seems like **getCallingActivity()** returns results inconsistently across different android platforms.

The issue is caused probably because you are setting the **launchMode** of your activity as ***singleInstance*** or ***singleTask***.
Setting it to ***singleTop*** or leaving it as the ***standard*** one should solve your issue.
Of course, changing the mode should not affect your use case so this is at your discretion.

In case it does affect your use case, you can pass the package name in the extras of the intent to simplify things.

Note that setting singleInstance or singleTask returns *non null* results on ***Lollipop*** release.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible your calling activity is finishing sooner than you're expecting it to. this happened to me and resulted in a null return from getCallingActivity, even though the calling activity was using startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem when the activity was declared with `singleInstance` as launch mode in the manifest. In my case, I found a solution without this declaration which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`getCallingActivity` can return `null` depending on the activity launch mode as others have pointed out. I was launching the activity by calling `startActivityForResult` passing in the intent returned by `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`. By default, it has the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag set and this caused the `getCallingActivity` to return `null`. Calling `intent.setFlags(0)` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Is t his setFlags supposed to be called on the initiating app or receiving?
I tried setting the flags to 0 when calling from App1  startActivityForResult(...)
But in App2 I still have getCallingActivity=null as well as getCallingPackage()..