# Getting name of Parent acitvity-Null Exception

Tags: android

I m getting NullPointerException whenever I try this-

```
getCallingActivity().getClassName()
```

I want to get the name of the `caller/parent` acitivity from the `called/child` activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the doc [`getCallingActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) returns the value only if the calling activity is expecting result i.e only if the activity is started with call to  `startActivityForResult`

So for most cases this wont work. A better approach would be to pass the value through intent. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289824/why-is-getcallingactivity-always-returning-null)

Comment: Definitely, I used -startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK); and in the called activity I used- getCallingActivity().getClassName() , trying to get the name of the calling activity but its giving NullPointeExcption.Pls help

Comment: so are you getting RESULT_OK in OnActivityResult after the called activity is finished?

Comment: I m not getting RESULT_OK in OnActivityResult, I used startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_OK); and setResult(RESULT_OK, data); but I dont know what RESULT_OK works for..

Comment: startActivityForResult should be called with a request code, not the result of the new activity that was launched.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible your calling activity is finishing sooner than you're expecting it to. this happened to me and resulted in a null return from getCallingActivity, even though the calling activity was using startActivityForResult

Comment: So, how did you fix this or keep the Activity from finishing?

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019156/detecting-activity-is-started-for-result/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289824/why-is-getcallingactivity-always-returning-null You can pass your activity as an Extra. Would that be a valid solution?

Answer (score 0):

the caller and called Activities must be in one task.
that is, you cannot start the called activity with any flag likes Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK