# Detecting activity is started for result

Tags: android, android-activity

I've an activity suppose "Activity A" which I start by two ways 
a)`StartActivity()` 
b) `StartActivityForResult()` 
Now I have few methods which are having different behaviours for the way activity started. Now I want to detect that "Activity A" is started for result.
So my question how we can detect that the activity is started for result?
I don't want to send data through intent. Any other way more generalized?

Thank You.

Comment: `send data through intent` itself is the optimized way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Send some **boolean Extra** when its called using

```
intent.putExtra("mBool", true);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Depending on that value, respective actions are done.

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("mBool")){

//ForResult
}else{

//default
}
```

Comment: Imho, bad solution. Why adding complexity to the application when you can simply check `this.getCallingActivity() != null`?

Comment: As I understand you can only get the calling activity when it's calling for a result. In case the activity is not calling for a result value, you couldn't change behavior depending on the calling activity. So In case you would have more than one activity calling another, you couldn't distinguish

Comment: Bad anwser as it is not using Android native solution

Comment: android native solution doesnt work either. if Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is set then null is returned with or with out starting for result

Answer (score 16):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17060830/2823516)

> When your activity was started just by startActivity() a
>   getCallingActivity() method in target activity will return null. When
>   it was called by startActivityForResult() it will return name of
>   calling activity.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> if (getCallingActivity() == null) {
>     //This Activity was called by startActivity 
> } else {
>    //This Activity was called by startActivityForResult
> }
> ```

Comment: it doesnt work when Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is set

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass any fake data in `Intent`. Activity has method for checking starting `Activity` it is called `getCallingPackage()`

From the documentation:

> Return the name of the package that invoked this activity. This is who
>   the data in setResult() will be sent to. You can use this information
>   to validate that the recipient is allowed to receive the data.